# Talend component kit. Define own schema

Tags: talend

The talend component tREST provides his own schema that is used as output schema

[image]

how to do the same with [talend development kit](https://talend.github.io/component-runtime/main/latest/index.html) ?

`DiscoverSchema` provides the schema only by click on `Guess schema` button

`@Structure(type = Structure.Type.OUT)` fills configuration parameter with user filled schema properties

My component requires specific input and output schema.

How to define them?